# Drupal 8 - How to display content from field collection inside a region?

Tags: drupal, view, content-type, drupal-8, region

I'm pretty new to Drupal,

I have created a View with a custom content type which includes a field collection. When i try to load this view block inside a region in front page, It just shows the title (with the link to the actual content) and not the content itself. I need to view the content in the front-page itself

Can you please help me how to do this?

Comment: can you post a picture with view settings? maybe the reason is the format of display of FIELD COLLECTION, check the format display in view settings and choice "content" , choice to option to show the content of field collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. if in view you selected show format as content then you have to add your field collection field in selected display
2. if in view you selected shoq format as fields then you have to add your field collection field in view fields section